# Linking files using relative path

Tags: html, css, path, relative-path, absolute-path

i have two folder named home and about in **plusone folder**.now i want to call the **home.html** in home folder from **about.html** in about folder

These solution did not work for me `href="home/home.html"` or `../home.html`

Comment: don't do web development from desktops. Invest 5 minutes to install a rudementary apache.

Answer (score 0):

Absolute path: `/home/home.html` or `/plusone/home/home.html`.

Relative path: `../home/home.html`. If you are in the `/plusone/about/` folder, with `../` you go to the parent folder (`/plusone/`) and with `../home/`, you go to the folder `/plusone/home/`.

Comment: i did not get result shiva :(